# Get Items Under Folder CAML

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I am trying to retrieve all items that are under a certain folder, in a document library.

This is what i have so far:

```
List DocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                        <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/>
                                    <Value Type='Text'>
                                        /ecm/Business/Business/Projects/IDECO_P01030000
                                    </Value>
                                </eq>
                            </Where>
                        </Query>
                        <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'> 30 </RowLimit>
                    </View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It is definitely a CAML query problem, I am just unsure of how to fix it as yet.

Comment: There was also bad casing for `Eq` operator. Being an XML dialect, CAML is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

I changed the scope from "Recursive" to "RecursiveAll", RecursiveAll gets all files and all folders under the specified location.

The CAML query was replaced with

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">/ecm/Business/Business/Projects/IDECO_P01030000</Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";
```

Comment: Sebastien,
Your code worked not because you changed the string.
It is because you changed the scope from "Recursive" to "RecursiveAll"
As RecursiveAll gets all files and all folders under the specidified location.

Comment: hahah, so i see i asked this question when i was till very new to SharePoint :), thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @SebastienStettler : Hey If i want to check multiple conditions by putting `<And>` in this query how can i achieve that...

Comment: @RahulGokani if you have questions about a specific answer, please use our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), not comments. Thanx!

Comment: this is worked ... <View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> .. in last two days i want to retrieve all task items in nested folders in task list and search google : summary task nested folders and so on... ( csom clientcontext )

Comment: Although this works, it places unnecessary load on SQL subsystem. A more proper way is to use FolderServerRelativeUrl as CMN suggests.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the FolderServerRelativeUrl property of the CamlQuery.
See: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

you should also try to load all the folders and files. means

```
 clientContext.Load(DocumentList);
 clientContext.Load(DocumentList.RootFolder);
 clientContext.Load(DocumentList.RootFolder.Folders);
 clientContext.Load(DocumentList.RootFolder.Files); 
 clientContext.Load(listItems);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

than you can get FolderCollection in Library

```
 FolderCollection FC = Document.RootFolder.Folders
 Foreach(Folder Fl in FC)
         {
                FileCollection flc = fl.files;
         }
```

Hops its help.

Answer (score 3):

To get items from specific folder without receursive add to query this options:

```
<QueryOptions>
 <Folder>thelist/thefolder</Folder>
</QueryOptions>
```

Note to replace **thelist/thefolder** with actual relative url

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using comparison operator as 'Contains'

```
    <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/> 
    <Value Type='Text'> 
        /ecm/Business/Business/Projects/IDECO_P01030000 
    </Value> 
    </Contains>
```

Comment: Contains operator is more resource intensive for SQL than Eq or In because the query engine cannot use an index.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all items in a list or library, including items in folders, support 5000+ items:

```
private async Task<List<ListItem>> GetAllListItems(ClientContext clientContext, List list)
{
    var result = new List<ListItem>();

    ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;
    while (true)
    {
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;
        camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                <ViewFields>
                                <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                                </ViewFields>
                                <RowLimit>5000</RowLimit>
                              </View>
                             ";

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

        itemPosition = listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;

        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }

        if (itemPosition == null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Woudln't it easier to use ´SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()´ or `SP.CamlQuery.createAllFoldersQuery()`?