# Get all Files from sub folder of a certain content type

Tags: document-library, content-type, folder, linq, query

my problem is I have a document library with sub folders. Also the document library got more than one content type.

Is there a way to create a CAML or LINQ query to get all files of a certain content type from one of this sub folders.

The sub folder name is known.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SPQuery, use [SPQuery.Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.folder.aspx) to define the folder:

```
SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder.SubFolders["Folder 1"];

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = folder;
```

Then, to define content type, you should include the following condition into your Where clause:

```
SPContentType contentType = list.ContentTypes["MyContentType"];
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='Text'>" + contentType.Id + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Then, to include all subfolders of "Folder 1", you should specify `Scope="Recursive"` in the query ViewAttributes:

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
```

P.S. In case you're using Client Object Model and CamlQuery, the syntax will be a bit different. I.e. instead of `Folder`, you will need [FolderServerRelativeUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx):

```
query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Shared Documents/Folder 1";
```

And also recursive scope is defined as attribute of the View element, which in this case should be included into query.

Comment: Great answer, but instead of "Name='ContentType'" it must be "Name='ContentTypeId'" when u use contentType.Id. Works perfectly!

Comment: Oh, my bad, just grabbed this piece from internet and didn't test it :( I'll correct the answer for further readers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create CAML query that looks something like this (I've ommited the unrelated parts):

```
<View>
..........
    <QueryOptions>
        <ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
    </QueryOptions>
    <Query>
      <Where>
          <And>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name="ContentType"></FieldRef>
                  <Value Type="Text">$Resources:ResourceFileName,ContentTypeName</Value>
              </Eq>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"></FieldRef>
                  <Value Type="Text">Server Relative URL of the Folder</Value>
              </Eq>
          </And>
      </Where>
    </Query>
..........
</View>
```

This will return all the documents of the specified content type in the specified subfolder.

Here are some links that might be useful:
[Get Items Under Folder CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml)
and
[Filter Document library folder through CAML Query](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/35e799a1-9360-46e5-8719-dd35fdace7ea)

Comment: Can you also show how to specify the folder to query in CAML?

Comment: I've edited the query. Hope it helps.