# Search by Folder name in different site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, query

I'm trying to setup a search query to look @ one specific folder name across site collections.

If I have the 3 site collections and similar "leader" folders of:

- SharePointMe.com/apples/GrannySmith/leader
- SharePointMe.com/grapes/concord/seedless/leader
- SharePointMe.com/tomatoes/green/frozen/leader

How can I get a query to look for anything in these 3 "leader" folders?

I'm trying this query text in query result sources, but it's not working:

SitePath:"SharePointMe*/leader"

So far, I'm testing this for my query:

```
SitePath:"http://www.SharePointMe*" Title:leader
```

...but this is relying on the title of the document to have "leader" in it, not really pulling everything back under the "leader" folder...which is what we need.

I have read too that prefix matching doesn't work, but was hoping the above scenario would...but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking directly for the folders, you'd probably want to query the 'Path' variable for all items where it contains 'leader'?

```
Path:{Site.URL}/leader
```

Plus, if you configure this at the root site collection, this should get all other site collections below as well. `{Site.URL}` could also be exchanged for `{SiteCollection.URL}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know witch SharePoint are you using 2010 or 2013 [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/get-all-files-from-sub-folder-of-a-certain-content-type) is a good answer how you can query folders with CAML query.

```
<FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"></FieldRef>
<Value Type="Text">Server Relative URL of the Folder</Value>
```

You can get the folder using  [SPQuery.Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.folder.aspx) and search for SPListItems from code behind.

Comment: 2013 version we are using

Comment: We are looking for something end users could update on an SCA (Site Collection Administrator) level, and not need to write code.

Comment: We have our search result working, though it's not very dynamic: SitePath:"sitename/sites/mainParent/ChildRecordCenter/Leader*" SitePath:"sitename/sites/mainParent/general/Leader*" This doesn't lend too well if we start to have 100+ sub-sites under "mainParent"...which is very possible.  Almost like TSQL where you can use the "%" character would be perfect to grab that "leader" folder.