# Update of field value in a file within document library using powershell is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server

I have associated a custom content type to a document library and this content type as multiple fields.

The `FieldXYZ` termset from which this field is derived has 2 values ('Success' , 'Failed').

In my PowerShell script, I am updating a field `FieldXYZ` value for all documents in the root directory of the library.

The PowerShell code for updating the field is as follows:

```
    $lists = $web.lists
foreach ($list in $lists) 
{
 if ($list.BaseType -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary) 
 {
    write-host "Document Lib : " , $list.title
        SetFieldValuebyGUID($list.RootFolder)   
        SetFieldValuebyVal($list.RootFolder)    
 }
}




Function SetFieldValuebyGUID($rootfolder)
    { 
      foreach($docfile in $rootfolder.Files)
      { 
        write-host $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"]
            $docfile.CheckOut()
        $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"] = n5f52e7f-bb83-4c01-xxxxxxxxx
        $docfile.Update();
        $docfile.CheckIn('updated property GUID')
            write-host $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"]
         }
       }


Function SetFieldValuebyVal($rootfolder)
    { 
      foreach($docfile in $rootfolder.Files)
      { 
        write-host $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"]
            $docfile.CheckOut()
        $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"] = "Success"
        $docfile.Update();
        $docfile.CheckIn('updated property GUID')
            write-host $docfile.Properties["FieldXYZ"]
         }
       }
```

The script is not updating the values of the field.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should change in your script:

1. You are using `$file.Properties` which are not exactly SPListItem metadata. You should use `$file.Item["fieldname"] = ...` To change document metadata.
2. As it seems you are trying to set a taxonomy field that is not so straightforward. You should look,at this blog post on how to set taxonomy field using powersell http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/15/updating-sharepoint-managed-metadata-columns-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: I have tried it by docfile.item [field name ] = value and docfile.item.update ()   , that was not updating the value.

Comment: Is it taxonomy field? If yes you should try set according to sample specified in the link.

Comment: Yes, it was a metadata field (part of custom contenttype) The field is also tried to termset. I will try the termset option

Comment: One thing I dont understand is, if I am using foreach file in folder, it does not update the data for parameter, when I use the foreach on listitems, update function will work.  Is there anyway to update items in a specific folder?                                     foreach ($file in folderparam.files)
{
$file.Item["parameter"] = GUID
$file.Item.Update() }


================
foreach ($item in $list.items)
{
$item["parametr"]  = GUID
$item.Update()

}

Comment: In thtis case, I would suggest, to make a `CAML` query on your list to get ListItems from specific folder and then make `foreach` through ListItemCollection. So make caml query on specific folder you can set SPQuery.Folder property, like showed in the anwer of this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/get-all-files-from-sub-folder-of-a-certain-content-type