# How to configure CAML Query Options to show items inside specific folder

Tags: caml-query, scope, getlist, subfolders

I wrote a java program that uses SharePoint's Lists web service.
Right now, this is my CAML Query :

```
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>SubFolder1</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

and this is my CAML Query Options :

```
<QueryOptions>
   <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
   <OptimizeFor>FolderUrls</OptimizeFor>
</QueryOptions>
```

This is what my root folder looks like :

[image]

And my program returns all **File3.txt**, **SubFolder2** and **File4.txt** 
What should I do in order to only get the contents of **SubFolder1** : **File3.txt** AND **SubFolder2** ?

Also, Is there a way to place myself on a folder other than root ?

Comment: I think you need to check `query.FolderServerRelativeUrl` chk http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/get-all-files-from-sub-folder-of-a-certain-content-type and http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010programming.aspx?ID=e37f16f3-44f5-48ad-962b-b0e6345ccc73

Comment: Thanks @Neel , I've been looking down that path the hole night but there's no way of using `FolderServerRelativeUrl` under **Java** environment and you can't insert it directly into the CAML Query file either.

Comment: yes you are right FolderServerRelativeUrl is for sharepoint api only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for thanks to this [Blog](http://www.mstechblogs.com/paul/lists-asmx-getlistitems-and-folders). 
I deleted the CAML Query settings :

```
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>SubFolder1</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

and added this line to my CAML Query Options file :

```
<Folder>http://MySharePointServer/Root/SubFolder1</Folder>
```

And changed the **Scope** to `All` instead of `RecursiveAll` so it would only bring items directly under **SubFolder1**.

So now this is my Final CAML Query Options File :

```
<QueryOptions>

    <Folder>http://MySharePointServer/Root/SubFolder1</Folder>  
    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>TRUE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>     
    <ViewAttributes Scope="All"/>   
    <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>     
</QueryOptions>
```

PS : you have to specify the hole URL to the SubFile. you cannot use RelativeUrl for this option.

Comment: Do you know if this works with a library over the item threshold limit?

Comment: No sorry @Webfort I didn't try that out