# Expose Contents of Subfolders via REST API

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, subfolders

I'm working on an Angular2 component that needs to expose the files in a document library but also the files within any subfolders of said document library. I've scoured the web for an answer and it looks like this is very doable -- I just seem to be coming up short.

The REST call is somewhat abnormal -- it's a search rather than a request for the document library:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='ListId:{{The List ID}} AND FileName<>"AllItems.aspx*"'
```

When I run this query with with no property limits I don't immediately see anything in the OData returned that would keep track of any subfolders' contents. I'm hoping maybe I can add an $expand that would take care of it?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally query your items using caml in the REST api like this:

```
var camlQuery = {
    ViewXml: "<View>" +
        "<Query></Query>" +
        "</View>"
}
```

then call `/_api/Web/Lists/getById('YourListId')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=' + JSON.stringify(camlQuery)`

see [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208020/make-caml-query-with-in-rest-api-call) on `CAML` and the REST-api, documentation is at [GetItems-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetItems).

Now, querying "items in a folder" *should* work like this (untested):

```
<View>
  <Query />
  <QueryOptions>
    <Folder>http://MySharePointServer/Root/SubFolder1</Folder>    
  </QueryOptions>
<View>
```

Have a look at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193925/how-to-configure-caml-query-options-to-show-items-inside-specific-folder), regarding `CAML` and folders.

However, reading the [docs to SP.CamlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600183.aspx#bk_CamlQuery) the following sounds promising, too:

```
var camlQuery = {
    FolderServerRelativeUrl: 'http://MySharePointServer/Root/SubFolder1',
    ViewXml: '<View><Query /></View>'
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Nils! I'm looking into the CAML approach now. I think one issue I'm having with other, similar posts is that I don't know what the subfolders will be. There will be document library "x", and inside that will be some documents I need information on but there will also possibly be folders made by users. If there are folders, I'd need to display all the the documents inside those folders as well without additional REST calls. Seems like your CAML recommendations are getting me much closer to that.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was helpful, consider marking it as such.