# How to apply a CAML query only on list root folder and not subfolders

Tags: sharepoint-server

I made CAML query to filter items in an `SPList` view but I want to apply this query only on the root folder of SPList, not the subfolders, because I copied items from the root folder to subfolder. When I want to open a subfolder I have to see the items there.
Because I have items to hide them from the main view and I copied them to subfolders

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Or>
      <And>
        <Or>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
              <Value Type='Computed'>Dossiers envoyés</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' />
              <Value Type='Computed'>Dossiers à suivre</Value>
           </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Or>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
              <Value Type='User'>system</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
              <Value Type='User'>redacteur</Value>
           </Eq>
        </Or>
     </And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Envoy_x00e9__x0020_vers_x0020_directeur' />
        <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
     </Eq>
   </Or>
  </Where>
</Query>


 // this is the filter that hide these items from the main view.
  then i moved them to the Dossiers envoyés subfolder when their value change from 0 
   to 1

    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Envoy_x00e9__x0020_vers_x0020_directeur' />
        <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
     </Eq>

 //my list root folder contains the followinf tree
 + dossiers envoyes
     - item 2
     - item 1
       ...
 + dossiers archive
    - item 1
    - item 2
     ...
 - item 1
 - item 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of my query before where i added

```
 <Or>
    <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /> 
      <Value Type="Text">/folderPath</Value>
   </Contains>
<Or>
```

it does work

Answer (score 1):

If you want items in a specific folder (root folder in your case), you can use `FileDirRef` column and filter based on it..

```
<Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /> 
   <Value Type="Text">/folderPath</Value>
</Eq>
```

Have a look at:

[Get Items Under Folder CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml)

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem to close the question :)

Comment: not yet unfortunately it's possible to modify my query