# SP2013 : Get data from folder inside a custom list

Tags: 2013, rest

How to get all data from folder inside a Sharepoint list using client side code ? Rest apis

Comment: answered here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml

Comment: not working as expected.