# Display particular folder list view

Tags: 2013, document-library, list-view, caml-query

I have document library in which several folders, in one of them I have sub-folder that I need to display in custom view. So, position of that folder is like **Doc.Library** > **Folder2** > **Internet**.
I found several examples how to display Folder instead of whole Library in custom view, with help of CAML query in SPD2013.

Here is what I have in my custom view:

```
<Where>
    <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name="FileRef"/>
        <Value Type="Text">Internet</Value>
    </Contains>
</Where>
```

Now comes part which gives me problem, with this query, I get blank page, no documents are visible. If I put **Folder2** instead of **Internet** I see documents but I see all documents of Folder2 folder, which I don't need.
So, my question is how can I manage to show Internet folder only?

I tried several other options, instead of Text to put Lookup, FileLeafRef instead of FileRef, etc. but none were successful.

Comment: Where you are using that caml query? c#?

Comment: I am using it in .aspx page of Custom view I created for that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minor changes I solved problem.
Instead of **FileRef** I put **FileDirRef**. For **View** I added **Scope="RecursiveAll"** and for Value I put relative address.

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
        <Value Type='Text'>/sites/sitename/subsitename/DocLibraryName/folderName/SubFolderName</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using c#, then you can use the following code

```
List DocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                        <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/>
                                    <Value Type='Text'>
                                        /DocLib/Folder2/Internet
                                    </Value>
                                </eq>
                            </Where>
                        </Query>
                        <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'> 30 </RowLimit>
                    </View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Ref [Click Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml)

Comment: Thanks for effort and your time. I voted your answer as useful.