# CAML query with ORDER BY is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, caml-query

Hi i have document library having custom column named **INDEX** of type **Number** and there is some folders and documents in document library like

[image: File/folder structure in document library]

I have created CAML query to get item having maximum Index value.

```
query += "<Where>";
query += "<IsNotNull>";
query += "<FieldRef Name='INDEX'/>";
query += "</IsNotNull>";
query += "</Where>";
query += "<OrderBy >";
query += "<FieldRef  Name='INDEX' Ascending='FALSE' />";
query += "</OrderBy>";

itemQuery.Query = query;
```

---

In result i am getting is below which is wrong.

In result  all folders are displaying and then files are displaying.

[image]

---

Excepted result should be like below.

[image]

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding *Override="TRUE" in* . Modified Code below:

```
query += "<Where>";
query += "<IsNotNull>";
query += "<FieldRef Name='INDEX'/>";
query += "</IsNotNull>";
query += "</Where>";
query += "<OrderBy Override="TRUE">";
query += "<FieldRef  Name='INDEX' Ascending='FALSE' />";
query += "</OrderBy>";

itemQuery.Query = query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You are CSOM  please kept the **Scope**  attribute value to **RecursiveAll** ? If you set the  scope from "Recursive" to "RecursiveAll", RecursiveAll gets all files and all folders under the specified location. please check the  sharepoint stackexchange post[Get Items Under Folder CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml)

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> "
```

Comment: I don't want to get all folder and files inside folder. I want folders and files from current folder only.

Comment: Then use linq query on the result(list item Collection) to sort and get the first row

Comment: That is wrong thing and will impact on performance.