# Sharepoint Online: Powershell recursive CAML query possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, caml-query, pnp-powershell

I was wondering if it's possible to write am CAML query in SPO Online that also let's me search elements within folders in a list, so basically a recursive one.

In combination with PnP Powershell I'm able to find elements with this:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $targetList -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef 
Name = 'FileLeafRef'/><Value Type = 
'Text'>Test.txt</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

However, this file is in the 'root' of the list. I'm not able to find test.txt if it lay in a folder.

I googled that CAML queries can have a 'scope' parameter 'query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'" that should do the trick. Unfortunately, I found no way to integrate this into PowerShell. In SharePoint 2013 it seems there's the possibility to create the query via the New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery class.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try `<View Scope='Recursive'>`

[ViewScope enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewscope.aspx)

Example,

[Get Items Under Folder CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml)

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-PnPListItem -List $targetList -Query "<View Scope=`"RecursiveAll`"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef 
Name = 'FileLeafRef'/><Value Type = 
'Text'>Test.txt</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

[View Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438338.aspx)

Comment: Thank you as well. I was able to successfully query what I intended to.