# Get all items of a Folder and subfolders using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query, caml

My scenario: I need to update 2 columns of items in a certain subfolder.But here the subfolder can contain subfolder and so on which i need to update too.I am using csom to try to accomplish that.I cant figure out how to recursively get all the items and once i get those item how to differentiate between files and folders

I can't get the item name to pass a relative url in the recursive function.

```
        private static  void GetFolderItems(string folderServerRelativeUrl, List list, ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        try
        {

            var query = new CamlQuery();

            query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderServerRelativeUrl;

            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + folderServerRelativeUrl + "</Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";

            ListItemCollection folderItems = list.GetItems(query);
            clientContext.Load(folderItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (ListItem item in folderItems)
            {
                if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
                {
                    item["Title"] = "Test";
                    item.Update();
                    list.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                }
                else if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
                {
                    // item is a folder
                    String SubFolderUrl = folderServerRelativeUrl + "/" + item["Title"]; 

                    GetFolderItems(SubFolderUrl, list,clientContext);

                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error occured");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you have the problem? Once you have the list instance, call the context manager ([ClientContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx) class) in order to load the properties you need. Then, just iterate over all folders to update them and all the items inside.

```
// Context.Current is the proper ClientContext instance
Context.Current.Load(listInstance.RootFolder);
Context.Current.Load(listInstance.RootFolder.Folders);

// This sentence returns the folder searching by its name
var folder = listInstance.RootFolder.Folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == title);
```

**EDIT: Retrieving list items**

Here you have a similar question, [Get Items Under Folder CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/get-items-under-folder-caml), I think this will help you a lot.

Besides, here you have the code I used in order to retrieve all items from a list. Maybe, changing this method and adding the proper CAML sentences you will be able to retrieve items from a folder.

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> GetItems(string title, params string[] fields)
{
    var list = Get(title);
    var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10000, fields);
    var items = list.GetItems(query);

    Context.Current.Load(list);
    Context.Current.Load(items);

    Context.Current.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach(ListItem item in items)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the first 2 line i got an idea how to iterate over the folders,now i want to know how to get the items of that folder and update it?

Comment: Edit my answer adding a link to a similar question you asked and some code I used to retrieve all items from a list.

Comment: how do i differentiate between files and folders then?

Comment: I think that changing the CAML query from my code and pasting the one that appears as the answer in the link provided will be enough. You will iterate through the folders and query for the items in there.

Comment: i got all the folders and files in the current directory but not files inside those folders

Comment: I suppose you have to create a recursive method from a folder. Given the root folder as the first call, it will iterate all items and when found a subfolder, call the method (recursively) passing that subfolder. The method will execute till iterates over all items in the tree that forms the items and folders.

Comment: i updated the question with codes,i cant seem to get the item name

Answer (score 1):

You can get the subfolders using RecursiveAll:

```
    List DocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">/sites/test/list/folder1</Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";
    ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
    {
       console.writeline(item["Title"]); 
    }
```

Comment: do i get the subfolders items using this query?

Comment: Yes. you can get all files and folders using RecursiveAll

Comment: how do i get each item Title?

Comment: Updated the previous response

Comment: when i use the code,it doesnt return me the name of the folders or files.I just get the name of only one powerpoint thats it.

Comment: i updated the question with codes,i cant seem to get the item name